# Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated

Tags: reactjs

Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
Occurred while linting /home/bash/Documents/react-genesis/src/App.tsx
[enter image description here][1]

App.tsx

```js
import {
  ChakraProvider,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { RecoilRoot } from "recoil";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import React from "react";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function AppContent() {
  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <Router>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>

              <AppContent />

            </QueryClientProvider>
        </Router>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Generally this line `"project": "./tsconfig.json"` under parserOptions on the eslintrc.json file is enough

Answer (score 6):

The [eslint docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/typed-linting) detail how to enable linting with type information as follows

```js
// eslint config

module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // should be already existing
  parserOptions: { // add this object
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },

  // other config

};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `.eslintrc.yaml` add:

```
parserOptions:
  project: ['./tsconfig.json']
```

just below `parser`. This worked for me.